# CSS3 animation not working as expected with Bourbon library

Tags: css, animation, bourbon

Using Bourbon to define CSS3 animation styles. I've been bashing my head against the wall for hours now trying to figure out what's going on. I'm trying to animate a once circle that's absolutely positioned on top of another circle. The circle starts off with the following styles in place:

```
.circle {
    $diameter: 50px;
    @include transform(translate(-15px, -15px));
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: $diameter;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    width: $diameter;
}
```

I've got a class that defines animation like this:

```
 &.circle-move {
  @include animation(circle-move, 3s, ease-in-out, 2);
}
```

And keyframes defined like this:

```
@include keyframes(circle-move) {
  0% {
    @include transform(translate(-15px, -15px));
  }

  12.5% {
    @include transform(translate(-30px, -30px));
  }

  25% {
    @include transform(translate(-30px, 0));
  }

  37.5% {
    @include transform(translate(0, 0));
  }

  50% {
    @include transform(translate(-15px, -15px));
  }
}
```

And yet there's no movement. What am i doing wrong!? Any help is appreciated.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyqdPM?editors=110

Comment: Your pen doesn't appear to have any JavaScript.

Comment: Correct, no Javascript. CSS3 animations.

Comment: This will learn me to not have so many tabs open (no it won't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use comma in the animation

```
 &.circle-move {
     @include animation(circle-move 3s ease-in-out 2);
}
```

Comment: AGGGHHHHH! Thank you.